# How can I get the decorators of a function?

Tags: python, cmd

I have a class, lets called `WindCMD`, which has functions with decorators

```
@options( 
             [
              make_option( '-s', '--windspeed',
                           default = 999,
                           help = "Set the wind speed." 
                           ),

              make_option( '-d', '--winddir',
                           default = 999,
                           help = "Set the wind direction." 
                           )                            
              ] 
             )     
def do_set_wind_manually( self, line, opts = None ):
```

There is a possibility to get all the functions of the class by using the `__dict__`, but how can I get the function decorator and the options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't in general.  A decorator just performs a pre-processing step on a function.  The object returned by the decorator may not even be the original function you defined (and in most cases that wrap a function it is not).  Once a decorator has done its job there is no *explicit* record left behind on the returned function that it was the result of a decorator on some other function.  You *could* define a decorator that sets some attribute on the function.  For example:

```
class options(object):
    def __init__(self, somearg):
        self.somearg = somearg

    def __call__(self, func):
        func.options = self
        return func

>>> @options('foo')
... def myfunc(): pass
...
>>> myfunc.options
... <__main__.options at 0x19f6d90>
>>> myfunc.options.somearg
... 'foo'
```

I suppose if you really needed to you could also write a decorator that wraps decorators and records them.  This is just a rough implementation of that idea:

```
class record_decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, decorator):
        self.decorator = decorator

    def __call__(self, func):
        result = self.decorator(func)
        if not hasattr(result, 'decorators'):
            if hasattr(func, 'decorators'):
                result.decorators = func.decorators[:]  # copy
            else:
                result.decorators = []
        result.decorators.append(self.decorator)
        return result

>>> def a(func):
...     print 'decorating with a'
...     return func
...
>>> def a(func):
...     print 'decorating with a'
...     return func
...
>>> @record_decorator(b)
... @record_decorator(a)
... def myfunc(): pass
...
decorating with a
decorating with b
>>> myfunc.decorators
[<function __main__.a>, <function __main__.b>]
```

Now `myfunc.decorators` contains a list of all decorators applied to the function in the order they were applied.  At least in principle--it still won't tell you about any decorators that were applied *without* using `record_decorator`.