# Generating an http client behind a typescript interface? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, javascript-decorators

I am trying to understand decorators which are not java's annotations but more like pre-processors [in this article](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) and I also found [this SO question on setting info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049065/how-can-i-get-the-decorators-of-a-function) on a function.  Let's say I have an interface like so

```
export default interface UserService {

    @Path("/users/create")
    @POST
    createUser(user: CreateUserRequest): Promise<CreateUserResponse>;

    @Path("/users/delete")
    @POST
    deleteUser(user: DeleteUserRequest): Promise<DeleteUserResponse>;

}
```

sidenote: It would be great to use this generated client in react UI as well as use in nodejs

I want my @Path and @POST, @GET to save info I can read and I think

```
class Path(path:string):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def __call__(self, func):
        func.pathAnnotation = self
        return func
```

I read I cannot loop over methods in an interface yet I would like to generate the http client that implements this interface so any API developers create, it automatically creates the implementation.  (In java, we use the Proxy.java to generate an implementation).  On server side, the controller implements the same exact API and I like to generate the 'scaffolding' meaning the http request to which endpoint to call if possible (not sure I can do that in nodejs just yet).

EDIT: An idea: Perhaps, I create an abstract class or class and every method throws an exception "Use XXXFactory to generate the implementation of this class".  How do I loop over method in that class?  and can I create classes that extend all these 'apis' at runtime such that I can inject him for everyone to use(like Proxy.java in java world)?

EDIT: perhaps I could do this in javascript with a prototype class somehow... generate all the methods to call a method with signature

```
Promise<Object> invoke(String method, object[] paramsToMethod);
```

Then, I can look up the method and @Path and @GET/@POST properties on that method.  Can a prototype class extend a class in javascript such that any api defined (perhaps defined in typescript) is implemented by this one class?  Then I have every api implemented by the same code for every microservice like we do in java?  (This then means the platform team can swap protocols and developers do not care about protocols anymore like http, http2, binary, etc)

Comment: Do you mean, taking an existing interface, and creating a "client" based off of its keys?

Comment: keys?  What I generally mean is if a client calls either method, a single method is called with the method so the implementation code can 1. lookup the properties on the method, 2. create an http request and 3. make the request and 4. return a response of the correct type.  We do this in java so NO ONE ever has to create the http client behind the API.  perhaps generating one behind a class could work as well.  It saves tons of time long-term for developers.

Comment: There's a terminology barrier here, so bare with me, but my understanding is you have an interface, and you want to be able to generate a method from the interface automatically rather than needing to code both the interface and the client. This is based on: "I would like to generate the http client that implements this interface so any API developers create, it automatically creates the implementation." My understanding is, this isn't possible with typescript because types are compile-time, not runtime. However, I'd suggest looking at transformers.

Comment: yes, it is hard to talk between languages ;).  In java, there is one method invoke in a special class Proxy and I that method will be passed the method name and params of any method invoked on the 'runtime class' such that I can create one class at runtime for all apis and maintain one class for all apis and all the methods in all those apis which varies only on my inspection of the method.  I need a way to funnel all method calls to one method in typescript.  I feel like there may be a way to do it with a javascript prototype or something perhaps?  thanks @KevinB at least for trying!!!

Comment: Possible with our new `Proxy` object in JavaScript but the performance with it is less than desirable. You could also use `Reflect` to redefine methods that wrap around the original.

Comment: @youdateme omg, amazing!!!   'premature optimization is the root of all evil' Donald Knuth.  ie. I am fine with it being not that performant.  In languages, they generally make this better over time anyways.  I optimize for decreasing time to market & dev productivity over performance.  At least until performance is an issue(based on the P&Ls I have worked with so far).

Comment: Ok, if you wish; let me just make a small working example first.

Comment: Hm actually, how is the client supposed to be generated so that it satisfies the service's expected type *dynamically*? You would definitely need some crazy reflection magic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per request, I have took some time to tinker around with reflection. The reflection is mostly needed to make the client automatically conform to what the service expects (type of parameters/return type), and I think it might be possible with `reflect-metadata`.

Ok so the idea is to have decorators store metadata about the method in a map, where a key is the class and the value is a collection of the methods with metadata.

Then where you get the client, it aggregates all the metadata for each method  into one function that can be used.

It's a vague start but I think it can work. I actually might also turn this into a small snippet or library too if I have the time.

But actually, this should be a statically generated client, not a dynamic one. Because then it is far easier to validate and do the code generation.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-tsDgYyVfJmpcAEizTQycoS1AH7UGOWMbqgx8VYZhRmbUxiSu5BjbOYnyHaZlmsv3MBbSI9rVTo4h0GyNQrmQKgemwVHhFifLCuqVBtCPTqDCMEwKq2vgk0KG1iA9pjFGkJlMC0G4WtCH2nZZ12rleJajxVuEgA)