# Typescript get parameter types which contains a parameter decorator

Tags: typescript

Why?
I am using NestJS and an API endpoint looks like this:

```js
  @Post('me')
  async me(@Req() req: Request, @Body() body: { someString: string }) {
    return { ok: body.someString };
  }
```

Now I want to create a function on the client with the body type: `{ someString: string }` as the parameter type:

```
async callMe(body: BodyParameterType) {
  // call api...
}
```

Is it possible to create the type `BodyParameterType` to get the body type from the api endpoint?

Comment: This question reminds me of a somewhat [similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71295986/generating-an-http-client-behind-a-typescript-interface-is-it-possible). I think you'd need a statically generated client, something like prisma does.

Comment: @youdateme yes looks like generating the client statically is a better option. Thank you didn't thought about it!